# How to process a large file in loop as input for another file

Tags: ruby

I have a large file which has more than 1M lines, and another file which has the input-strings I need to use to get the lines matching in the large file.

I was able to do it this way:

```
File.open(strings_file, 'r') do |l|
  File.open(large_file, 'r') do |line|
    next if !line.include?(l)
    puts line
  end
end
```

But, it will open the large file for each loop. For example, in input-strings, I have 100 lines of strings, so when it executes it will open that large file 100 times to process it, which takes more time to complete.

Is there way faster method to avoid opening the large file 100 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you'll have a geometric scaling problem if you get this wrong. If input file A has N lines and B has M lines then you'll need to do N*M tests to check for overlap. That can be impossibly slow.

Instead, pull in the input lines and stick them in something you can use for quick lookups:

```
require 'set'
match_lines = Set.new(File.readlines(strings_file).map(&:chomp))
```

Then you can test very quickly here:

```
File.foreach(large_file) do |line|
  print line if (match_lines.include?(line.chomp))
end
```

I'm using `chomp` here to avoid failing to match if the last line in your match file doesn't have a newline at the end or if you're using CRLF encoding in one and LF in the other.

Comment: Nice! But its not working due to match_lines are just plain strings and line variable value would contain both special characters and string. I think we need to perform the `(match_lines.include?(line.chomp))` in reverse way. Not sure how to do it in reverse way.

Comment: What do you mean about the "reverse way"? What sort of content are you talking about in the `strings_file`?

Comment: strings_file contents:

`test
word
amber
red
blue`

Larger_file contents which matched with the above mentioned strings:

`'test, this is t3e$t file' and 'location /mnt'

.
.

blue, the color is blue and 'which is part of RGB'`

Hope am making clear now

Comment: Do you want to check on a word-match basis or a complete line?

Comment: Note how @tadman used `foreach` to open and iterate over the lines in the file. That's idiomatic in Ruby.

Comment: @tadman I want to check on word-match basis not complete line

Comment: @tadman could you please let me know how to check on word-match basis

Comment: @Karthick I answered your original question. If you have a new one it's best to post it as a new question so other people can focus on that particular problem.